# Regex parse text with multiple recurring optional blocks

Tags: regex

I have a configuration output that I want to parse using regex. I want to capture every proxy-set definition including its proxy-ip config which is optional.

I have succeeded to have 2 matched groups with 1 proxy-ip but the second proxy-ip isn't captured. Also it doesn't capture a proxy-set without proxy-ip set.

I tried the following regex in regex101: `((proxy-set.*?((proxy-ip.*?)exit).*?)) /gms`

```
       proxy-set 2
    proxy-name "Teams"
    proxy-enable-keep-alive using-options
    proxy-load-balancing-method random-weights
    is-proxy-hot-swap enable
    tls-context-name "Teams"
    sbcipv4-sip-int-name "Teams"
    activate
    proxy-ip 0
     proxy-address "sip.pstnhub.microsoft.com:5061"
     transport-type tls
     priority 1
     weight 1
     activate
    exit
    proxy-ip 1
     proxy-address "sip.pstnhub.microsoft.com:5061"
     transport-type tls
     priority 1
     weight 1
     activate
    exit
   exit
   proxy-set 2
    proxy-name "Teams"
    proxy-enable-keep-alive using-options
    proxy-load-balancing-method random-weights
    is-proxy-hot-swap enable
    tls-context-name "Teams"
    sbcipv4-sip-int-name "Teams"
    activate
    proxy-ip 0
     proxy-address "sip.pstnhub.microsoft.com:5061"
     transport-type tls
     priority 1
     weight 1
     activate
    exit
    proxy-ip 1
     proxy-address "sip.pstnhub.microsoft.com:5061"
     transport-type tls
     priority 1
     weight 1
     activate
    exit
   exit
   proxy-set 3
    proxy-name "Teams"
    proxy-enable-keep-alive using-options
    proxy-load-balancing-method random-weights
    is-proxy-hot-swap enable
    tls-context-name "Teams"
    sbcipv4-sip-int-name "Teams"
    activate
   exit
```

Comment: What is the tool or language?

Comment: The output is a cli script of an AudioCodes SBC, the parsing I will do using PowerShell using regex class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Powershell, you can make use of 2 capture groups, where you can get the repetitive values of the capture group 2 values from the [Captures Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures?view=net-6.0).

```
(?m)^[\p{Zs}\t]*(proxy-set\b.*(?:\r?\n(?![\p{Zs}\t]*proxy-(?:set|ip)\b).*)*)(?:\r?\n(proxy-ip\b.*(?:\r?\n(?![\p{Zs}\t]*proxy-(?:set|ip)\b).*)*\r?\nexit))*
```

**Explanation**

- `(?m)` Inline modifier to enable multiline
- `^` Start of string
- `[\p{Zs}\t]*` Match optional leading spaces
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `proxy-set\b` Match literally and append a word boundary
  - `.*` Match the rest of the line
  - `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

    - `\r?\n` Match a newline
    - `(?![\p{Zs}\t]*proxy-(?:set|ip)\b).*` Match the whole line if it does not start with *proxy-set* or *proxy-ip*
  - `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat
- `)` Close group 1
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\r?\n` Match a newline
  - `(` Capture **group 2**

    - `proxy-ip\b.*` Match proxy-ip

      - `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

        - `\r?\n` Match a newline
        - `(?![\p{Zs}\t]*proxy-(?:set|ip)\b).*` Match the whole line if it does not start with *proxy-set* or *proxy-ip*
      - `)*` Close the non capture group and repeat as a whole part
      - `\r?\n` Match a newline
    - `exit` Match literally
  - `)` Close group 2
- `)*` Optionally repeat the outer non capture group which will have capture group 2 in the repetition and can be retrieved using the Captures Property

See a [.NET regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6Tl9fX/1)

Powershell example to see the different values:

```
$txt = Get-Content -Raw file.txt

$pattern = "(?m)^[\p{Zs}\t]*(proxy-set\b.*(?:\r?\n(?![\p{Zs}\t]*proxy-(?:set|ip)\b).*)*)(?:\r?\n(proxy-ip\b.*(?:\r?\n(?![\p{Zs}\t]*proxy-(?:set|ip)\b).*)*\r?\nexit))*"
Select-String $pattern -input $txt  -AllMatches |
        ForEach-Object { $_.Matches } |
        ForEach-Object {
            Write-Host "`n------ group 1 value ------`n"
            Write-Host $_.Groups[1].Value
            
            foreach($capture in $_.Groups[2].Captures) {
                Write-Host "`n------ group 2 capture value ------`n"
                Write-Host $capture.Value
            }        
        }
```

Or an example of [the pattern](https://regex101.com/r/HbW3mg/1) where the lines can have optional leading spaces.